# Problems using xcode in debug mode with Core Plot

Tags: cocoa, xcode, debugging, frameworks, core-plot

I'm having a problem compiling an application which uses Core-Plot in debug mode. It works absolutely fine compiling in release mode, but when I compile in debug mode I get an error that the header file for Core-Plot can't be found. Any idea which of the many settings in x-cide might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you added the path to the Core Plot headers to your target's Header Search Paths only for the Release configuration instead of All Configurations.